# Problema com ngModel no Angular 2

Tags: angular

Estou tentando pegar os valores de 3 inputs que estão em um modal do Ionic 2 mas ele dá esse erro: `Error in ./ModalPage class ModalPage - caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

O meu código dos inputs está assim:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" placeholder="Nome">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefone">
```

Eu até tentei fazer da seguinte forma: `[ngModel]="model?.name` mas aí não retorna nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está recebendo esse erro porque o seu componente não possui uma propriedade "model". Inicie o objeto com todas as propriedades para evitar o erro:

```
export class MeuComponente {

  model: Model = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: ''
  };
}
```

ou crie uma classe com as propriedades de model e inicie uma nova instância:

```
import { Model } from '/.model'; 

export class MeuComponente {

  model: new Model();

}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui resolver aqui :)